# Поиск символа python

Tags: python

пытаюсь найти в такой строки символ скобки и его почему-то не находит.

```
strings = 'video 1/1 (1/430) /home/odinson/Рабочий стол/2_5204360658820275976.mp4: 640x384 (no detections), 113.6ms'
if strings.find('(') == True:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

Мне нужно чтобы возвращало булевое значение, поэтому пытаюсь использовать этот метод.

Comment: [str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) возвращает число. Сравнивать его с истиной `1234 == True` не имеет практического смысла.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy понял, что-то явно напутал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
#strings = 'video 1/1 (1/430) /home/odinson/Рабочий стол/2_5204360658820275976.mp4: 640x384 (no detections), 113.6ms'
strings='/home/odinson/Рабочий стол/'
res=strings.find('(')
print(res)
if strings.find('(')==-1:
    print('no')
else:
    print('yes')
```

Вывод:

```
-1
no
```

или
условие найденная позиция больше нуля

Answer (score 2):

[str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) возвращает число. Сравнивать его с истиной (`1234 == True`) не имеет практического смысла.

Используйте [in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in):

```
if '(' in strings:
    ...
```